# PHP curl_setopt errors

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Error received is:

```
{
  "code": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "message": "Invalid request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/periodKey"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/vatDueSales"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/vatDueAcquisitions"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/totalVatDue"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/vatReclaimedCurrPeriod"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/netVatDue"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/totalValueSalesExVAT"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/totalValuePurchasesExVAT"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/totalAcquisitionsExVAT"
    },
    {
      "code": "MANDATORY_FIELD_MISSING",
      "message": "a mandatory field is missing",
      "path": "/finalised"
    }
  ]
}
```

my code is:

```
$headerData = [
    'Accept: application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $strAccessToken ,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
$postData = json_encode(array(
    'periodKey' => $strPeriodKey ,
    'vatDueSales' => $rngBox1 ,
    'vatDueAcquisitions' => $rngBox2 ,
    'totalVatDue' => $rngBox3 ,
    'vatReclaimedCurrPeriod' => $rngBox4 ,
    'netVatDue' => $rngBox5 ,
    'totalValueSalesExVAT' => $rngBox6 ,
    'totalValuePurchasesExVAT' => $rngBox7 ,
    'totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT' => $rngBox8 ,
    'totalAcquisitionsExVAT' => $rngBox9 ,
    'finalised' => $chkFinaliseConfirm
)); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,          1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    $headerData);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Endpoint info can be found here:
https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/api/service/vat-api/1.0
but in principle is:

> /organisations/vat/{vrn}/returns
>
> Submit VAT return for period POST  Submit VAT return for period POST
> Submit VAT return for period. This endpoint is one of the mandatory
> endpoints to use to achieve the minimum level of compliance. The other
> endpoint required to achieve the minimum level of compliance is
> Retrieve VAT obligations.
>
> Authorisation This endpoint is user-restricted and requires an
> Authorization header containing an OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token with the
> write:vat scope.
>
> Path parameters Path parameters table Name    Description vrn string
> required VAT registration number. A nine-digit number.
>
> For example: 123456789
>
> Request headers Request headers Table Name    Description Accept required
> Specifies the response format and the version of the API to be used.
>
> For example: application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json Content-Type required
> Specifies the format of the request body, which must be JSON.
>
> For example: application/json Gov-Test-Scenario optional Only in
> sandbox environment. See Test Data table for all header values.
>
> For example: - Authorization required An OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token with
> the write:vat scope.
>
> For example: Bearer bb7fed3fe10dd235a2ccda3d50fb See also fraud
> prevention.
>
> Request Scenario: VAT Return with decimals {   "periodKey": "A001",
> "vatDueSales": 105.50,   "vatDueAcquisitions": -100.45,
> "totalVatDue": 5.05,   "vatReclaimedCurrPeriod": 105.15,
> "netVatDue": 100.10,   "totalValueSalesExVAT": 300,
> "totalValuePurchasesExVAT": 300,   "totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT":
> 3000,   "totalAcquisitionsExVAT": 3000,   "finalised": true }
> Scenario: VAT Return with a hash in the periodKey {   "periodKey":
> "#001",   "vatDueSales": 100.00,   "vatDueAcquisitions": 100.00,
> "totalVatDue": 200.00,   "vatReclaimedCurrPeriod": 100.00,
> "netVatDue": 100.00,   "totalValueSalesExVAT": 500,
> "totalValuePurchasesExVAT": 500,   "totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT":
> 500,   "totalAcquisitionsExVAT": 500,   "finalised": true } Request
> table Name    Description periodKey string required The ID code for the
> period that this obligation belongs to. The format is a string of four
> alphanumeric characters. Occasionally the format includes the #
> symbol.
>
> For example: 18AD, 18A1, #001
>
> vatDueSales number required VAT due on sales and other outputs. This
> corresponds to box 1 on the VAT Return form. The value must be between
> -9999999999999.99 and 9999999999999.99.
>
> vatDueAcquisitions number required VAT due on acquisitions from other
> EC Member States. This corresponds to box 2 on the VAT Return form.
> The value must be between -9999999999999.99 and 9999999999999.99.
>
> totalVatDue number required Total VAT due (the sum of vatDueSales and
> vatDueAcquisitions). This corresponds to box 3 on the VAT Return form.
> The value must be between -9999999999999.99 and 9999999999999.99.
>
> vatReclaimedCurrPeriod number required VAT reclaimed on purchases and
> other inputs (including acquisitions from the EC). This corresponds to
> box 4 on the VAT Return form. The value must be between
> -9999999999999.99 and 9999999999999.99.
>
> netVatDue number required The difference between totalVatDue and
> vatReclaimedCurrPeriod. This corresponds to box 5 on the VAT Return
> form. The value must be between 0.00 and 99999999999.99
>
> totalValueSalesExVAT number required Total value of sales and all
> other outputs excluding any VAT. This corresponds to box 6 on the VAT
> Return form. The value must be in pounds (no pence) between
> -9999999999999 and 9999999999999.
>
> totalValuePurchasesExVAT number required Total value of purchases and
> all other inputs excluding any VAT (including exempt purchases). This
> corresponds to box 7 on the VAT Return form. The value must be in
> pounds (no pence) between -9999999999999 and 9999999999999.
>
> totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT number required Total value of all
> supplies of goods and related costs, excluding any VAT, to other EC
> member states. This corresponds to box 8 on the VAT Return form. The
> value must be between -9999999999999 and 9999999999999.
>
> totalAcquisitionsExVAT number required Total value of acquisitions of
> goods and related costs excluding any VAT, from other EC member
> states. This corresponds to box 9 on the VAT Return form. The value
> must be between -9999999999999 and 9999999999999.
>
> finalised boolean required Declaration that the user has finalised
> their VAT return.
>
> For example: true
>
> Response headers Response headers Table Name  Description
> X-CorrelationId required Unique id for operation tracking String, 36
> characters.
>
> For example: c75f40a6-a3df-4429-a697-471eeec46435 Receipt-ID required
> Unique reference number returned for a submission String, 36
> characters.
>
> For example: 2dd537bc-4244-4ebf-bac9-96321be13cdc Receipt-Timestamp
> required The timestamp from the signature, in ISO8601 format
>
> For example: 2018-02-14T09:32:15Z Receipt-Signature required This
> header is not currently used
>
> For example: DO NOT USE See also fraud prevention.
>
> Response HTTP status: 201 (Created)
>
> {   "processingDate": "2018-01-16T08:20:27.895+0000",
> "paymentIndicator": "BANK",   "formBundleNumber": "256660290587",
> "chargeRefNumber": "aCxFaNx0FZsCvyWF" } Response table
> Name  Description processingDate string required The time that the
> message was processed in the system.
>
> formBundleNumber string required Unique number that represents the
> form bundle. The system stores VAT Return data in forms, which are
> held in a unique form bundle.
>
> Must conform to the regular expression ^[0-9]{12}$
>
> paymentIndicator string optional Is DD if the netVatDue value is a
> debit and HMRC holds a Direct Debit Instruction for the client. Is
> BANK if the netVatDue value is a credit and HMRC holds the client’s
> bank data. Otherwise not present.
>
> Limited to the following possible values:
>
> DD BANK chargeRefNumber string optional The charge reference number is
> returned, only if the netVatDue value is a debit. Between 1 and 16
> characters.
>
> Error scenarios Error scenarios table Scenario    HTTP status Code
> Invalid VRN
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> VRN_INVALID
>
> Invalid period key
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> PERIOD_KEY_INVALID
>
> Invalid request
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> INVALID_REQUEST
>
> totalVatDue should be equal to the sum of vatDueSales and
> vatDueAcquisitions
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> VAT_TOTAL_VALUE
>
> netVatDue should be the difference between the largest and the
> smallest values among totalVatDue and vatReclaimedCurrPeriod
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> VAT_NET_VALUE
>
> Please provide a numeric field
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> INVALID_NUMERIC_VALUE
>
> The monetary amount is invalid
>
> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> INVALID_MONETARY_AMOUNT
>
> User has not declared VAT return as final
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> NOT_FINALISED
>
> User has already submitted a VAT return for the given period
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> DUPLICATE_SUBMISSION
>
> Return submitted too early
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> TAX_PERIOD_NOT_ENDED
>
> The client and/or agent is not authorised. This is normally because:
> the client is not subscribed to MTD, the agent is not subscribed to
> Agent Services, or the client has not authorised the agent to act on
> their behalf.
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> CLIENT_OR_AGENT_NOT_AUTHORISED
>
> The request could not be completed as it relates to an insolvent
> trader, which are not supported by this API.
>
> 403 (Forbidden)
>
> RULE_INSOLVENT_TRADER
>
> For error scenarios that are common across all APIs, and for error
> formats, see our reference guide.
>
> Test data Scenario simulations using Gov-Test-Scenario headers are
> only available in sandbox environment.
>
> Using this endpoint in the sandbox environment will store the data
> submitted. There is no requirement to use the periodKeys in the
> obligation response in the sandbox environment.
>
> Header Value (Gov-Test-Scenario)  Scenario INVALID_VRN
>
> Submission has not passed validation. Invalid parameter VRN.
>
> INVALID_PERIODKEY
>
> Submission has not passed validation. Invalid parameter PERIODKEY.
>
> INVALID_PAYLOAD
>
> Submission has not passed validation. Invalid parameter Payload.
>
> DUPLICATE_SUBMISSION
>
> The remote endpoint has indicated that VAT has already been submitted
> for that period.
>
> TAX_PERIOD_NOT_ENDED
>
> The remote endpoint has indicated that the submission is for a tax
> period that has not ended.
>
> INSOLVENT_TRADER
>
> Simulates the scenario where the client is an insolvent trader.
>
> Close section

I've tried changing the format of post data into an array using different methods but none of them seem to like the format I am passing.
Question is why am I getting the above error messages when I am using the above code?

tia m@

Comment: For what it's worth, those error messages come from the API end-point, not the Curl extension. If the API is yours, what format should the request have? If it's a third-party app, what does the documentation say?

Comment: are you sure that API accepts json? not urlencoded post?

Comment: Thankyou for your feedback, I'm very very new at API calls and I only began learning PHP about 3 weeks ago so all in all, I don't think I'm doing too bad.

Comment: You double encode your post fields: first `$postData = json_encode(array` then `$jsonPostData =json_encode($postData);`. Remove one and see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try url encoded post:

```
$headerData = [
    'Accept: application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $strAccessToken ,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
$postData = array(
    'periodKey' => $strPeriodKey ,
    'vatDueSales' => $rngBox1 ,
    'vatDueAcquisitions' => $rngBox2 ,
    'totalVatDue' => $rngBox3 ,
    'vatReclaimedCurrPeriod' => $rngBox4 ,
    'netVatDue' => $rngBox5 ,
    'totalValueSalesExVAT' => $rngBox6 ,
    'totalValuePurchasesExVAT' => $rngBox7 ,
    'totalValueGoodsSuppliedExVAT' => $rngBox8 ,
    'totalAcquisitionsExVAT' => $rngBox9 ,
    'finalised' => $chkFinaliseConfirm
); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,          1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    $headerData);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by _"Try url encoded post"_, since there is no URL encoding in your answer (the only change is that you have removed one call to `json_encode`).

Comment: yes, because if you will give an array as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it will assume that you wan't to send it as urlencoded and will encode it automatically like `periodKey=$strPeriodKey&vatDueSales=$rngBox1(...)`, but if you give a string (JSON string) it will send it directly... depedning of API (end-point) some of them accept one way, some other, some both... your seems not to accept JSON.